# How can I use Bixby to generate "onClick()" event on a view in an Android activity

Tags: samsung-mobile, bixby

I want to use Samsung Bixby to generate "onClick()"-like events in an activity of my Android app (the activity has several buttons and I want to use voice commands with Bixby to click on them). How can I do it?

The app is written in Java.

I have read the Bixby Getting Started guide but I still don't understand how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Adding more information as my previous answer may not have been detailed enough.

Bixby currently does not support interactions within your app. I would recommend that you raise a Feature Request in [our community forum](https://support.bixbydevelopers.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/360000183273-Feature-Requests). This forum is open to other Bixby developers who can upvote it, leading to more visibility within the community and with the Product Management team.

To provide more insight:

The intended end-user experience is that a user starts a conversation with Bixby and a capsule you have developed to handle relevant requests will be used to work towards a solution. Your capsule can use the available REST API functionalities to make any necessary requests to your server/backend. If your solution requires it, you can also launch your app from Bixby.

It is not possible, however, for your app to launch Bixby.